# Как удалить все строки в текстовом файле, начинающиеся с определенного символа?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Как удалить все строки в текстовом файле, начинающиеся с определенного символа?

```
3EVbz7mBRpKBeBp6Qjq1b1uMYtRgTcTLyc
3DwBwG6khA63MSCgjrhBRRVpEBibbHuur9
3BYv2L9zCFYpvRQXakqkVWa7JyRw6Q9ZAm
35fe2CM2zbMeSfhRjpjW8ikTJcZj8NooFD
33QoG5ioV4hseifKT9iaqrmD2eis7DicWA
1ucXXZQSEf4zny2HRwAQKtVpkLPTUKRtt
1P1iThxBH542Gmk1kZNXyji4E4iwpvSbrt
1LfV1tSt3KNyHpFJnAzrqsLFdeD2EvU1MK
```

например из этого списка удалить все строки, начинающиеся с "3"
Нужна команда или скрипт, т.к. файл очень большей и notepad++ не подойдёт. Спасибо

Comment: Читаете строки в массив, перебираете, удаляете ненужные строки, записываете, повторяете, пока файл не кончится. Ну или по одной строке - читаем, проверяем, если нужна, записываем.

Comment: Не могу сейчас рабочий вариант написать, но вот [это](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback) почитайте. Я уже как-то писал очень простой парсер для своих нужд, там совсем коротенький скрипт получился.

Comment: А зачем нода, если есть grep/sed/awk и т.п.?

Answer (score 1):

батник:  findstr /B /V /C:3 in.txt >> out.txt